# Reorder rasterplots in R spplot

Tags: r, plot

how can I tell the spplot function in R to sort the rasters in a different order?
Here I have an example with 12 rasters, but I want them in 2 rows and 6 columns instead of 3 rows and 4 columns.
I found the grid.arrange function but it doesn't help me because it would plot all rasters including the colour scale.
Here is some code to create an example:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 10, ncols = 10, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.3)
rr <- lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1))))
rstack <- stack(rr)
spplot(rstack)
```

[image]

Comment: Provide some example dataset so that we can try to solve your problem. Please visit how to make reproducible example in r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spplot(rstack, layout = c(2,6))` will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `spplot(rstack, layout = c(6,2))` rather `spplot(rstack, layout = c(6,2))`. It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).